# how to get product details in admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, admin, grid

here is my `prepareCollection` from this how to get product name and price and status

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore(); 
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')    
                       ->getCollection() 
                       ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$this->_getProductId())
                       ->addFieldToFilter('link_type_id','1');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: For what purpose do you need 'product name and price and status'? To display in grid?

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi i have a grid in admin page. in the grid i am showing product_id , related_product_id and i want to show the product name and and price status. show that user can understand which product have related products.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi help me man.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your product link collection class and add a method

```
public function addProductData($attributesCodes)
{
    foreach ($attributesCodes as $attributeCode) {
        $attributeTableAlias = $attributeCode . '_table';
        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);

        $this->getSelect()->join(
           array($attributeTableAlias => $attribute->getBackendTable()),
             "main_table.product_id = {$attributeTableAlias}.entity_id AND {$attributeTableAlias}.attribute_id={$attribute->getId()}",
        array($attributeCode => 'value')
    );
        $this->_map['fields'][$attributeCode] = 'value';
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Then in your block's `_prepareCollection()` you can call this method

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore(); 
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')    
                   ->getCollection() 
                   ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$this->_getProductId())
                   ->addFieldToFilter('link_type_id','1');
    $collection->addProductData(array('name', 'price', 'status'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Now you can add `'name', 'price', 'status'` columns in `_prepareColumns()`.

Comment: i am getting this below error
Fatal error: Call to a member function addProductData() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Mk\Myproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Myproduct\Grid.php on line 59